# When sorting using statements with DevExpress Refactor Pro can I make it so all System namespaces are at the top?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devexpress, coderush, refactorpro

i want all of the system usings at the top (sorted alphabetically) and then all other using statements afterwards (sorted alphabetically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make Refactor Pro to do it your way.
Open "DevExpress -> Options -> Editor -> Refactoring -> Optimize Namespace References" and set relevant options according to your preferences.

[image: Optimize Namespace References]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about RefactorPro, but since the question is tagged with "visual-studio-2008", you can do it in VS'08 by going to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# (or whatever is relevant) -> Advanced and then ticking "Place 'System' directives first when sorting usings".

Comment: advantage of the refactor tool is that it becomes a part of the same refactoring shortcut that you use for everything else.... yeah you can make that shortcut the same but it'll be nice if it is all in one place...

Answer (score 1):

RefactorPro / CodeRush both have refactorings to....

- Optimize namespaces (remove unused namespaces)
- Sort Alphabetically
- Sort by length

Additionally there are (3rd party) plugins that sort in many other ways.

For example: [Refactor_SortNamespacesByScope](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/Refactor_SortNamespacesByScope)

Additionally, although the asker does not require this, these products also work VS2005.